# How do I setup an Elite HTTP Squid Proxy with password protection on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, http-proxy, squid

I would like to setup an Elite HTTP Proxy. An [Elite proxy](https://tech.tiq.cc/2012/06/differences-between-transparent-anonymous-and-elite-proxy/) should not expose any information about the source to the destination address. I have hired a Ubuntu virtual private server for this purpose. The proxy should be password protected, so that only I can use it. I would like to use [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) as my proxy.

What are the steps to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update your APT repository and install the software we will need**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install squid3
sudo apt-get install apache2-utils
```

Squid3 is the proxy software. apache2-utils is required for [htpasswd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html) which we will use as a flat file password store to secure the proxy.

**Setup the password store**

```
sudo touch /etc/squid/passwords
sudo chmod 777 /etc/squid/passwords
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/squid/passwords USERNAME
[prompt for new password]
```

In the lines above, replace USERNAME with the username you want on your proxy. When the line is executed you will be prompted to enter a password for the user.

**Test the password store**

```
/usr/lib/squid3/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwords
```

After executing this line the console will look like its hung, there is a prompt without any text in it. Enter "USERNAME PASSWORD" (replacing these with your specific username and password) and hit return. You should receive the response "OK". If not, review the error message, your username/password might be incorrect. Its also possible basic_ncsa_auth is located on a different path (e.g. lib64).

**Configure the Squid Proxy**

Move the default squid configuration file

```
sudo mv /etc/squid/squid.conf /etc/squid/squid.conf.original
```

Now create a new squid configuration file

```
vi /etc/squid/squid.conf
```

Which should look like this

```
http_port 3128
dns_v4_first on
cache deny all
forwarded_for delete
tcp_outgoing_address 9.9.9.9   //-- change this ip
via off
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwords
auth_param basic realm proxy
acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow authenticated
http_access deny all
```

Here is a description of what each line does:

- http_port: specifies the proxy listen port. This is required
- dns_v4_first on: effectively turns off IPv6 DNS. Without this your proxy may run *very* slowly.
- cache deny all: stops the proxy caching pages
- forwarded_for delete: remove the forwarded_for http header which would expose your source to the destination
- tcp_outgoing_address: **Set this to the address of your server**. You can find the address with the command "ip a"
- via off: removes more headers which would expose your source
- auth_param: defines your the location of your basic_ncsa_auth and password file you created. Note you may need to check the location of basic_ncsa_auth.
- acl authenticated: creates an access control list for user authenticated by the password store
- http_access allow authenticated: allow user to access the proxy if they have been authenticated by password
- http_access deny all: if you have not been authenticated by password, you're not coming in

**Restart the squid proxy**

```
service squid restart
```

Note the service could also be called squid3. It may take a while for the proxy to restart. If you prefer, you can reload squid configurations with the command

```
squid -k reconfigure
```

**Check its working**

```
service squid status
```

The service should be running.

```
netstat -ltnp
```

You should see a service listening on port 3128, or whichever port you used in the configuration.

On your desktop, open firefox, go to Options-> Network Proxy -> Settings. Choose to use a manual proxy configuration. In the HTTP proxy field enter the IP address of you server, and include the port in the port field. Click OK.

[image]

Go to google, enter your username and password when prompted, search "what is my ip address", you should see the IP of your proxy server.

Comment: If you get
"htpasswd: command not found"

Then you need to do the following
"sudo apt-get install apache2-utils"

Comment: `/usr/lib/squid3/basic_ncsa_auth: No such file or directory`

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, you might find basic_ncsa_auth is installed on a different path (in particular the lib64 folder)

Comment: The command 'curl ipinfo.io/ip' will show your real IP address (IP address of the Squid client if squid is transparent). Not searching 'what is my ip address'.

Comment: Sadly its not functioning.